# Can't see corresponding to control in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have something like this in Site.Master in an asp.net mvc3 (not razor) project:

```
<telerik:RadRibbonBar ID="RadRibbonBar1" runat="server">
```

The code behind is defined as such:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="myproject.Site_Master" CodeFile="Site.Master.cs" %>
```

So Site.Master.cs is:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System;

namespace myproject
{
    public partial class Site_Master : ViewMasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

How can I access radribbonbar1 from Page_loaded (which does get called once the page loads).

I was under the impression by giving it an ID it would be autogenerated to be accessible via C# code but that isn't happening (there is no variable radribbonbar1 available to Site_master).

Any ideas for how to make this work?

Comment: Check your Site_Master.designer.cs file . I tried to put label control and i am able to access .. it is MVC 3 Project

Comment: Server controls will not work properly because they require event handling, which you do not have in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server controls will not work properly because they require event handling, which you do not have in ASP.NET MVC. See the [jQuery ribbon plugin](http://jqueryribbon.codeplex.com/)

Comment: so is it impossible to use the ribbon in an mvc3 website?

Comment: Controls that post back to the server don't work because MVC doesn't use eventhandling mechanism like WebForms. The most we can do is render a static server control like a label.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test this with your example but something like this might work

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
    return root.ID == id ? root : (from Control c in root.Controls select FindControlRecursive(c, id)).FirstOrDefault(t => t != null);
}
```

And, in your page_load

```
RadRibbonBar radRibbonBar1 = (RadRibbonBar)FindControlRecursive(Page, "RadRibbonBar1");
```